# Replacing DataFrame index values in python with conditional argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace some string values in an index column in a pandas data frame. The indexes are country names, and I want to replace strings like 'United Kingdom of England and Northern Ireland' with 'UK'.

The data framelooks like this:

```
data = ['12','13','14', '15']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Republic of Korea','United States of America20', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland19','China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region'],columns=['Country'])
```

I have tried:

```
d={"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
   "United States of America20": "United States",
    "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland19": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}  
df.index = df.index.str.replace(d)
```

Unfortunately, I just get an error message that replace is missing a positional argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas for `replace` values in `index` or `columns` is used function [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = df.rename(d)
print (df)
               Country
South Korea         12
United States       13
United Kingdom      14
Hong Kong           15
```

For me timings are practically same:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)

In [11]: %timeit df.rename(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 75.7 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit pd.Series(df.index).replace(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 71.8 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit pd.Series(df.index.values).replace(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 75.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you please add `pd.Series(df.index.values).replace(d)` to your timeit list as well?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialise a series and call `pd.Series.replace`:

```
df   
                                                   Country
Republic of Korea                                       12
United States of America20                              13
United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ir...      14
China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region          15


df.index = pd.Series(df.index).replace(d)
df

               Country
South Korea         12
United States       13
United Kingdom      14
Hong Kong           15
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)

%timeit df.rename(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 116 ms per loop

%timeit pd.Series(df.index).replace(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 96.7 ms per loop
```

I can squeeze out more speed using `df.index.values`:

```
%timeit pd.Series(df.index.values).replace(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 88 ms per loop
```

Timings will vary on your machine, so be sure to do your own tests before deciding what method to go with.

Comment: Hmmm, what is your pandas version? I test timings too and it is very similar. I use `0.21.0` under `win7` with `python3`.

Comment: @jezrael 0.21 on python3.4 (Ipython5), MacOS. My machine is a bit old so timings would vary.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Great to see all the alternatives